# How to schedule Sqoop import from Mysql and load in HDFS using Airflow 2.5.0

Tags: mysql, airflow, sqoop, airflow-webserver

I want to learn Airflow and thus am performing following task.

I want to read data from MySQL DB and load it to HDFS. I am doing this task using sqoop manually.

Now I want to schedule this activity using Airflow.

I have written the following DAG which will perform this task. But I am stuck in creating the Conn_ID for MySQL, Sqoop, HDFS.
I am here to seek some inputs can you kindly help me out here.

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.sqoop_operator import SqoopOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


Dag_Sqoop_Import = DAG(dag_id="SqoopImport",
                      schedule_interval="* * * * *",
                      start_date=days_ago(2))

sqoop_mysql_import = SqoopOperator(conn_id="sqoop_local",
                                  table="shipmethod",
                                  cmd_type="import",
                                  target_dir="/airflow_sqoopImport",
                                  num_mappers=1,
                                  task_id="SQOOP_Import",
                                  dag=Dag_Sqoop_Import)

sqoop_mysql_import
```

Replies Appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sqoop but in terms of Airflow connections [this guide](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/connections) might be helpful. If you have the connection URI to your tools you can use an env variable like `AIRFLOW_CONN_MYCONNID='my-conn-type://login:password@host:port/schema?param1=val1&param2=val2'` . If there is no specific connection type you can try `generic://`.

Comment: Also notice you are using old import syntax, you might want to check out the Airflow 2+ sqoop provider: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-sqoop/stable/index.html

Comment: Word of caution: sqoop was retired a few years ago, and the [sqoop git repository](https://github.com/apache/sqoop) hasn't seen a commit in over a year. See https://sqoop.apache.org/